# custom parsley form validation not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, parsley.js, parsley

I have a form with one field that needs a custom validator for which I'm trying to use Parsley v2.2.0-rc1 and jQuery 2.1.4.  I have confirmed that both jQuery and Parsley are loading (in that order) using my browser's developer tools to ensure I get HTTP 200 for all files.  Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
<html>
  <form id="stuff" data-parsley-validate>
    <textarea id="stuffList" data-parsley-stuffList></textarea>
    <input type="submit">Submit</input>
  </form>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="parsley.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="mycode.js"></script>
</html>

mycode.js:
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    window.Parsley.addValidator('stuffList', {
      requirementType: 'string',
      validateString: function(value) {
                        console.log('Starting validation');
                        if (something) {
                          return true;
                        } else {
                          return false;
                        }
                      },
      messages: {en: 'That stuff is not valid.'},
    });
  });
```

When I click submit, I don't even get the console.log message to let me know that the validation function was even called.  What am I doing wrong?

P.S. I've tried it both with the parsley-data-validate in the form tag and not, and with some value set for data-parsley-stuffList and not.  None of those variations cause the validator to execute.

Answer (score 1):

Add your validator to `ParsleyValidator` object likes so

```
window.ParsleyValidator.addValidator('stufflist', function(value, requirements) {
    console.log('Starting validation');
    if (value == 'something') {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}, 34);
```

add the custom message

```
window.ParsleyConfig.i18n.en.stufflist='That stuff is not valid.'
```

Verify that your validator exists by checking this in the console

```
ParsleyValidator.validators
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `data-parsley-stuff-list` instead of `data-parsley-stuffList`,
and `data-parsley-validate` instead of `parsley-data-validate`...

Comment: If I use data-parsley-stuff-list, then the validator name would have to be "stuff-list".  The name isn't really the issue though - it can be named whatever (I've changed it several times) and the validator still doesn't fire.

Comment: Parsley camelizes data attributes.

Comment: Actually
    data-parsley-stuff-list doesnt work either, it would have to be    data-parsley-stuff_list. Had this problem yesterday and thats how I got my validator to work.

Comment: Validator name: `stuffList`. Attribute name: `data-parsley-stuff-list`. That's the recommended style.